# Trying to "WriteLine" to a text file

Tags: c#, file, text-files

I am quite new to C# and I am trying to work with files. Right now I have only been calling from a file.

I am coming from Java so most of this is familiar. But I can't get a hold of this error:

```
StreamReader config = new StreamReader("config.txt");
String test = config.ReadLine();
String cow = File.ReadLines("config.txt").Skip(3).Take(1).First();
Console.WriteLine(cow);
config.WriteLine("text test");
//      ^ERROR^
```

Under "WriteLine" I get an error saying:

> "'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a definition for
>   'WriteLine' and no extension method 'WriteLine' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.IO.StreamReader' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am pretty sure I am not missing a using directive because I have:

```
using System.IO;
```

If you have any questions or info please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need a StreamWriter to write to a file not a StreamReader.

Answer (score 4):

As the name suggest, `StreamReader` reads a stream of bytes, in your case, those bytes happen to represent characters which in turn forms a `String`.

`File.ReadLines()` uses the `StreamReader` behind the scenes to read every line of a specified file, returning an `IEnumerable<string>`. Since you're using `File.ReadLines()`, there is no reason to be declaring a `StreamReader` variable since you're not actually using it to read the file.

Now from what I understand, what you're attempting to do is write to your configuration file again. To do this, you will need to use the `StreamWriter` which you can use like this.

```
const string ConfigurationFilePath = "config.txt";

using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationFilePath))
{
    writer.WriteLine("text test");       
}
```

Comment: Hey Colin, if you've found any of these answers helpful, please mark the one most helpful to you so that the community can benefit from it too :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as others have mentioned the StreamReader is for reading.  Here is an example of the SteamWriter in action:

```
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("config.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine("text test");
        file.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`StreamReader` is for reading files, what you need is [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter)'s a simple tutorial to get you started.